# How to get around the glmer warning : “Downdated VtV is not positive definite”

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I hope that I'm not asking a silly question but I looked at similar issues (including opened issues on github [#173](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/173) and [#396](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/396)) and couldn't find a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance for the time taken to look at the problem.

I have data that look like the simulation below. In the data there are 3 different groups (g1, g2 and g3) of subjects which needed either 1, 2 or 3 procedures (p1, p2, p3) respectively according to the gravity of the disease varying between subject. Hence, there is only p1 for the group g1; p1, p2 for the group g2; p1, p2, p3 for the group g3. Each measurement was performed at the time of each procedure. What I'm trying to do is the run to fit a mixed model logistic regression (sorry if it's not the correct nomenclature: I'm happy to learn if it's wrong) to look for difference in the proportion of patients at p1 who got a certain treatment (`y1` a dichotomous variable) and to control for the id the patient by setting it as a random variable.

With this simulated data, the output of

`mod_glmer = glmer(y1 ~ procedure + (1|id), data = data_g2, family = binomial)`

gives me the following error:

`Error in length(value <- as.numeric(value)) == 1L : Downdated VtV is not positive definite`

My guess is that it has to do with the fact that at `p1` there are only `1`'s when running the following:

`table(data_g2$y1[data_g2$procedure == "p1"])`

whereas there are both `0`'s and `1`'s at `p2` when running the following:

`table(data_g2$y1[data_g2$procedure == "p2"])`

However I also ran the a similar "standard" logistic regression and don't get the error message:

`mod_glm = glm(y1 ~ procedure, data = data_g2, family = binomial)`

What should I do to demonstrate that the proportion of `y1` is different in `p1` compared to `p2` using `glmer`?

P.S.: if you simulate the data, run several time as it involves generation of random number (I get the message around once every 2 runs if at random, it gives me an error each time with `set.seed(1)`. Try maybe another number `n` in `set.seed(n)` if you don't get the error message)

**Simulation of the data**

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

set.seed(1)

# define the number of subjects in each groups
n_g3 = 20
n_g2 = n_g3 * 10
n_g1 = n_g3 * 10

# 3 different groups
id_p1 = paste0("ID",1:c(n_g1 + n_g2 + n_g3))
id_p2 = paste0("ID",c(n_g1+1):c(n_g1 + n_g2 + n_g3))
id_p3 = paste0("ID",c(n_g1 + n_g2+1):c(n_g1 + n_g2 + n_g3))
id = append(append(id_p1, id_p2), id_p3)

# 3 different groups
groups = c(rep("g1", n_g1), rep("g2", n_g2), rep("g3", n_g3), rep("g2", n_g2), rep("g3", n_g3), rep("g3", n_g3))

# 1st, 2nd or 3rd procedure
procedure = c(rep("p1", n_g1), rep("p1", n_g2), rep("p1", n_g3), rep("p2", n_g2), rep("p2", n_g3), rep("p3", n_g3))

# measurement n??2 dichotomous
y1 = c(rep(1, n_g1 + n_g2 + n_g3),
  (rbinom(c(n_g2 + n_g3),1,0.8)),
  (rbinom(n_g3,1,0.3))
)

data = data.frame(id, groups, procedure, y1)

### create subset g2 of data to make comparisons within the group with 2 procedures
data_g2 = data[which(data$groups == "g2"),]

table(data_g2$y1[data_g2$procedure == "p1"])
table(data_g2$y1[data_g2$procedure == "p2"])

mod_glm = glm(y1 ~ procedure, data = data_g2, family = binomial)
summary(mod)

mod_glmer = glmer(y1 ~ procedure + (1|id), data = data_g2, family = binomial)
summary(mod_glmer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that allowed me to answer the question (thanks to @SalMangiafico  who helped in for a [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368272/why-does-logistic-regression-doesnt-give-the-same-result-as-a-chi-square-test-w)):

```
library(blme)

glmb = bglmer(y1 ~ procedure + (1|id), data=data_g2, family=binomial,
              fixef.prior = normal(cov = diag(9,2)))

pairs(emmeans(glmb, ~ procedure))
```

Output:

```
contrast estimate        SE  df z.ratio p.value
p1 - p2  7.779445 0.9237406 Inf   8.422  <.0001

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale.
```

For the theoretical explanation, I will largely copy part of the explanation of the [author of the package `bglmer`](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2015q1/023267.html). When a group contains all 0s or 1s (which is the case in this dataset) this can induces convergence failure. In that situation, the "Cauchy prior does a good job of pulling the extreme cases back down to earth while leaving the well-estimated ones roughly in place. As I'm far from being a statistician, I'm happy to learn the possible wrong facts about my answer.